# Unable to build the app in golang with oracle db

Tags: oracle, go

I am a beginner in go lang development and I try to connect the cloud oracle DB from go server(using 'github.com/godror/godror' package).
I install the Oracle instant client and set the environment path also.

Go server is running and able to establish the connection and queries. But when I am building a production app got these errors.

Command: `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o odb db_main.go`

````
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:452:53: undefined: VersionInfo
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:461:53: undefined: VersionInfo
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:479:19: undefined: VersionInfo
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:480:19: undefined: VersionInfo
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:481:30: undefined: ObjectType
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:482:31: undefined: Event
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:482:42: undefined: SubscriptionOption
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:482:64: undefined: Subscription
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:483:10: undefined: StartupMode
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:484:11: undefined: ShutdownMode
../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:484:11: too many errors```



My server code(db_main.go)
```package main
import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"


_ "github.com/godror/godror"
)


//  VersionInfo,ObjectType,Event,SubscriptionOption,Subscription,StartupMode,ShutdownMode
var db *sql.DB

func main() {
    var err error

    db, err = sql.Open("godror", "xyz/abc@13.43.11.8:1521/sampledb")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    port := ":8000"
    http.HandleFunc("/insert", InsertData)
    http.HandleFunc("/list", GetList)
    log.Println("Tranzo-Shahi Oracle DB running in ", port)
    httpErr := http.ListenAndServe(port, nil)
    if httpErr != nil {
        log.Println("Tranzo-Shahi Oracle DB Error: ", httpErr.Error())
    }
}
````

Comment: where is your error message ?

Comment: Error message mentioned on the top of the code, start from "../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:452:53: undefined: VersionInfo" and end this line "../github.com/godror/godror/orahlp.go:484:11: too many errors```".

Answer (score 0):

Run `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o odb` and don't specify any file. If you do specify one, like `db_main.go` then you need to specify all the files it the package that must be included in the build.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately original question has no mentioning of where the build run. It's important to know.

*godror* documentation points to possible problems when you try cross-compile your code. It's in their documentation: `Cgo is required, so cross-compilation is hard, and you cannot set CGO_ENABLED=0!`

I would suggest to run your build on Linux machine. (Verify it has *gcc* installed.)

Run your build as `env CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o odb`