godror error orahlp.go:563:19: undefined: VersionInfo
I am new to Go with Oracle SQL DB connection, I just created a Go project and setting up for it to connect to my Oracle DB, below are some of the info of my setup, and what I have tried to troubleshoot.

Ubuntu 22 WSL
installed Oracle instant client
tested connection with SQLplus
still hitting below error when "go run main.go"


github.com/godror/godror
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:563:19: undefined: VersionInfo
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:564:19: undefined: VersionInfo
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:565:10: undefined: StartupMode
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:566:11: undefined: ShutdownMode
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:568:31: undefined: Event
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:568:42: undefined: SubscriptionOption
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:568:64: undefined: Subscription
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:569:31: undefined: ObjectType
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:570:59: undefined: Data
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:571:28: undefined: DirectLob
../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/godror/godror@v0.44.7/orahlp.go:571:28: too many errors


main.go content as below:
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/godror/godror"
)

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("godror", `user="user" password="password" connectString="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=<ip-address>)(Port=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<sid>)))"
                               libDir="/opt/oracle/instantclient_23_5"`)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to open connection: %v", err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    // Ping the database to verify the connection
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to the database: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected to Oracle Database!")

}



I know this question similar to below, but no clear answer as what to do in below question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830964/unable-to-build-the-app-in-golang-with-oracle-db

If it’s the same question, you can add your answer to the existing question.

reference: https://github.com/godror/godror/issues/115
Need to make sure you have a working C compiler installed on your system to build and run Go applications that use godror
for Ubuntu 22:
Step 1: Install a C Compiler
The most common C compiler used with Go is gcc. You can install it along with other essential build tools using the following command:
sudo apt update

sudo apt install build-essential

This will install gcc, g++, make, and other essential tools needed to compile C programs.
Step 2: Verify Installation
You can verify that gcc is installed correctly by checking its version:
gcc --version

